# Install4J Install Process Fails on charsets step

Tags: install4j

We have some users with this error in the Install4J log during installation. Any ideas on what could be causing this? (Windows 7 64 bit)

```
[2:746] extracting Welcome.html (size 955)
[2:746] untaring JRE was successful
[2:762] JRE is packed
[2:762] checking jre\lib\charsets.jar
[2:762] Unpacking JRE
[2:762] jre\bin\unpack200.exe
[2:762] -r "jre\lib\charsets.jar.pack" "jre\lib\charsets.jar"
[3:11] could not create unpack process
```

Comment: perhaps we need to make sure unpack200.exe exists on the user's machine already?

Comment: No, that executable is part of the JRE. Do you have anti-virus software running? Try disabling it and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Yes AntiVirus software is running, but we cannot disable because the machines are tightly managed. We found a workaround - install on another machine, zip the installation, and make a one-off installer for this customer based on that zip. Not ideal but it works.